# C# locating where the * is in a string separated by pipes

Tags: c#, indexof

I have to find where a * is at when it could be none at all , 1st position | 2nd position | 3rd position.

The positions are separated by pipes  |
Thus

No * wildcard would be

```
`ABC|DEF|GHI`
```

However, while that could be 1 scenario, the other 3 are

```
    string testPosition1 = "*|DEF|GHI";
    string testPosition2 = "ABC|*|GHI";
    string testPosition3 = "ABC|DEF|*";
```

I gather than I should use  IndexOf , but it seems like I should incorporate | (pipe) to know the position (  not just the length as the values could be long or short in each of the 3 places.   So I just want to end up knowing if * is in first, second or third position ( or not at all )

Thus I was doing this but i'm not going to know about if it is before 1st or 2nd pipe

```
if(testPosition1.IndexOf("*") > 0) 
{
    // Look for pipes?  
}
```

Comment: Split the string at the pipe, then get the index of the entry that contains *

Comment: Let `targetIndex` be `IndexOf("*")`, `firstPipeIndex` be `IndexOf("|")`, and `secondPipeIndex` be `LastIndexOf("*")`. If `targetIndex` is less than `firstPipeIndex`, then `*` is in first position. If `targetIndex` is between `firstPipeIndex` and `secondPipeIndex`, then it's in the second position. Otherwise (i.e. > `secondPipeIndex`), then it's in the third position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways you could approach this. The most readable might actually just be to do it the hard way (i.e. scan the string to find the first `'*'` character, keeping track of how many `'|'` characters you see along the way).

That said, this could be a similarly readable and more concise:

```cs
int wildcardPosition = Array.IndexOf(testPosition1.Split('|'), "*");
```

Returns `-1` if not found, otherwise 0-based index for which segment of the `'|'` delimited string contains the wildcard string.

This only works if the wildcard is exactly the one-character string `"*"`. If you need to support other variations on that, you will still want to split the string, but then you can loop over the array looking for whatever criteria you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with linq splitting the string at the pipe character and then getting the index of the element that contains just a *

```
var x = testPosition2.Split('|').Select((k, i) => new { text = k, index = i}).FirstOrDefault(p => p.text == "*" );
if(x != null) Console.WriteLine(x.index);
```

So the first line starts splitting the string at the pipe creating an array of strings. This sequence is passed to the Select extension that enumerates the sequence passing the string text (k) and the index (i). With these two parameters we build a sequences of anonymous objects with two properties (text and index). FirstOrDefault extract from this sequence the object with text equals to * and we can print the property index of that object.

Comment: I'd expect the OP to be new to C#. Hence, LINQ will just confuse him.

Comment: To have fun just add `if (x != null) write...` or use `Console.WriteLine(x?.index ?? "Not found")`

Comment: Ok,  performance vs. all the other answers...  thoughts?

Comment: Also, I see that is anonymous type the var x...  I was trying to convert to int as I was to have a switch case statement for the results of  x

Comment: Probably not good. As explained by Peter in a deleted comment there are implicit loops just to get the index. If you want to benchmark these answers try using Linqpad and the Stopwatch class.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are fine (and likely better), however here is another approach, the good old fashioned *for loop* and the try-get pattern

```
public bool TryGetStar(string input, out int index)
{
   var split = input.Split('|');
   for (index = 0; index < split.Length; index++)
      if (split[index] == "*")
         return true;
   return false;
}
```

Or if you were dealing with large *strings* and trying to save allocations. You could remove the `Split` entirely and use a single parse *O(n)*

```
public bool TryGetStar(string input, out int index)
{
   index = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
      if (input[i] == '|') index++;
      else if (input[i] == '*') return true;
   return false;
}
```

Note : if performance was a consideration, you could also use `unsafe` and *pointers*, or `Span<Char>` which would afford a small amount of efficiency.

Comment: How is performance on this, compared to all other answers INCLUDING Steve's Linq ?

Comment: @JeremyMiller id have to benchmark them all, for large strings even the arrays access would likely beat any split or linq solution and would be fairly competitive against IndexOf, however id need to benchmark to be certain of arrays / pointers / span and IndexOf

Comment: @JeremyMiller: As Michael notes, the only useful way to understand performance is to measure. Fact is, unless you have to perform this operation millions of times in a short period of time, performance is unlikely to differ appreciably regardless of solution. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63892165) is the only one that doesn't generate new objects, and so in theory would be the most efficient. ...

Comment: ... But memory allocations are practically free in .NET (it's the garbage collection that can slow things) and otherwise it's much the same computational work regardless of which approach you take. Performance differences would only be noticeable in scenarios that really tax the algorithm, i.e. the millions of iterations I mentioned previously.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DotNETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V8c1m0):

```
testPosition.IndexOf("*") - testPosition.Replace("|","").IndexOf("*")
```

Find the index of the wildcard ("*") and see how far it moves if you remove the pipe ("|") characters. The result is a zero-based index.

Comment: This produces an unnecessary string allocation for the `Replace` call, which is unneeded.

Comment: @Youssef13 How does that compare to the overhead of [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1) or LINQ?

Comment: I'd just benchmark to answer. But I think a one pass loop should be more efficient than Split, LINQ, and Replace.

Answer (score 0):

From the question you have the following code segment:

```cs
if(testPosition1.IndexOf("*") > 0) 
{
}
```

If you're now inside the `if` statement, you're sure the asterisk exists.

From that point, an efficient solution could be to check the first two chars, and the last two chars.

```cs
if (testPosition1.IndexOf("*") > 0) 
{
    if (testPosition1[0] == '*' && testPosition[1] == '|')
    {
        // First position.
    }
    else if (testPosition1[testPosition.Length - 1] == '*' && testPosition1[testPosition.Length - 2] == '|')
    {
        // Third (last) position.
    }
    else
    {
        // Second position.
    }
}
```

This assumes that no more than one `*` can exist, and also assumes that if an `*` exist, it can only be surrounded by pipes. For example, I assume an input like `ABC|DEF|G*H` is invalid.

If you want to remove this assumptions, you could do a one-pass loop over the string and keeping track with the necessary information.

Comment: Note that while this fails "readability" and only works for a known-in-advance number of segments (i.e. 3), it also avoids allocation of new objects (whether iterators, new string instances, etc.). In most cases, the latter would be unimportant. But if the check needed to be done millions of time in quick succession, this approach would be ideal. _Aside: it would be even better to save the `IndexOf()` result in a variable, and then compare to `0` and `.Length - 1` instead of using an indexer to retrieve a character for comparison._